# Can't install pytorch =1.7 with python 3.8.5 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I am tried installing the `PyTorch v1.7.0` on my Raspberry device from the source on `python 3.8.5` version. I followed the following commands:

**Installation of Dependencies:**
`sudo apt install libopenblas-dev libblas-dev m4 cmake cython python3-dev python3-yaml python3-setuptools`

**Building the Options:**

```
export NO_CUDA=1
export NO_DISTRIBUTED=1
export NO_MKLDNN=1 
export BUILD_TEST=0
export MAX_JOBS=4
```

**Compiled and finally Installed:**

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch --recursive && cd pytorch
git checkout v1.7.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
python3.8 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It got successfully configured, compiled, and installed the PyTorch on my RPi but when I tried testing that then it threw the error for me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

**NOTE: I am using 32bt Ubuntu OS on my Raspberry Pi with python versions 2.7, 3.7, and 3.8 installed. I want to build the PyTorch on python version 3.8 only due to other projects requirement.**

**Since, I want to run this project [ultralytics/yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) which has the requirements of `python3.8`, `torch>=1.7`, and `torchvisin>=0.8` so that's why I want to build this with this versions.**

**Mine is Raspberry pi armhf**

if anyone has any idea, please help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: `python3.8 setup.py bdist_wheel` generates a wheel distribution, it doesn't install anything. You can either install the generated wheel using pip, or use `python3.8 setup.py install`.

Comment: @tttapa you mean to say that after following this command 'python3.8 setup.py bdist_wheel' I should run this command? - 'python3.8 setup.py install'

Comment: The easiest is probably to do `python3.8 -m pip install ./path/to/generated.whl`. You would use the command `python3.9 setup.py install` _instead of_ `python3.8 setup.py bdist_wheel`. Given that you already built everything, it's easier to just install the wheel without building everything from scratch again, I'm not sure if the build is cached.

Comment: @tttapa since I am already in the pytorch folder after following the above commands so do you think that I can run directly "python3.8 setup.py install" in the same folder instead of the other paths related command you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to install this after doing "python3.8 setup.py install"